# someting wrong when i use my dataset instead of musdb18 in this program

Tags: audio, pytorch, dataset

I'm trying to use https://github.com/amanteur/BandSplitRNN-Pytorch the project code, try to use my own data set instead of MUSDB18 data set, the result error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject4\BandSplitRNN-Pytorch-main\src\prepare_dataset.py", line 154, in 
main(
File "D:\pythonProject4\BandSplitRNN-Pytorch-main\src\prepare_dataset.py", line 148, in main
run_program(file_path, target, db, sad)
File "D:\pythonProject4\BandSplitRNN-Pytorch-main\src\prepare_dataset.py", line 108, in run_program
indices = sad.calculate_salient_indices(y)
File "D:\pythonProject4\BandSplitRNN-Pytorch-main\src\data\preprocessing.py", line 129, in calculate_salient_indices
indices = torch.arange(mask.shape[-1])[mask] * self.step_size
IndexError: tuple index out of range
could you tell me how can I solve this problem?
PS: My data set was recorded with a mobile phone, and the sample rate was also 44100, which was in wav format

i hope some good people can tell me how can i fix the problem